Zombienet is not working. Getting `Error parsing spec file`
I have a solochain that I'm trying to run using zombienet with a simple script. Everything works fine until I make any modifications to the chain.
Here is my block-building.toml:
[relaychain]
default_command = "./target/release/example"
chain = "local"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "alice"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"


Here is the command:
./zombienet-macos-arm64 -p native spawn ./zombienet/0000-block-building/block-building.toml

However, whenever I add a new pallet, which utilizes offchain-worker and session-handler, I encounter the following error while running Zombienet:
Error: Service(Other("Error parsing spec file: missing field `pallet_new_template` at line 102 column 13"))

I also want to highlight one more thing:
As I mentioned earlier, my new pallet introduces offchain-worker and session-handler, which adds a new session key to the chain.
Could this change be related to the issues I'm experiencing with Zombienet? If so, I would appreciate any help in resolving this.
Thanks for your assistance!

You can view the command utilized by the zombienet in the log. Take that command and execute it on your own.
It will resemble something like target/release/example --chain local ... This should report the same error.
I believe the issue is that your local chain specification is incomplete (incompatible with zombienet's).

I'm confident it's nearly the scenario I referred to earlier. I came across this a few months back.
The reason is that, for best compatibility, they didn't introduce any breaking changes for --raw output. That's the reason why the raw one works for you. But they improved the structure of the non-raw spec. My chain depends on an old polkadot-sdk version at that time, and the zombienet depends on a new one; it can't analyze the old non-raw output to generate the raw one.
Why does zombienet need to do this? Because it needs to modify the non-raw output, for example, inject some session keys. Then generate the raw file. The different versions of the non-raw structure cause this problem. You have to upgrade your polkadot-sdk dependencies or find a zombienet version that is compatible with your node.

I don't think so. following commands are working fine:

./target/release/example build-spec --chain local --disable-default-bootnode > local-plain.json
./target/release/example build-spec --chain local-plain.json --raw --disable-default-bootnode > localSpec.json

I wanted to share an observation regarding the spec generation in zombienet.
I've noticed that zombienet generates specs in two locations: one inside the cfg folder and another outside of it. When converting to a raw spec, zombienet seems to be picking the version outside the cfg folder.
When I manually convert the raw spec from outside cfg, I encounter the same issue. However, converting the raw spec from inside cfg works without any problems.
I’m unsure why zombienet is not selecting the spec from inside the cfg folder.

I'm sure about this. And I updated my answer.
